# Is it possible to add two Dirac Deltas?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is adding two Dirac Deltas defined?

diracDelta(t) + diracDelta(t) = 2 diracDelta(t)

Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Yes great Idea, add them together!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dirac delta is a distribution, also called a generalized function (under no circumstance is it ever ever *ever* **EVER** allowed to say that the dirac delta is a function). As such, since addition is defined on the set of all distribution, you can, indeed, get a new distribution by adding two dirac deltas.

Since the dirac delta $\delta_{x_0}$is the distribution that, when integrated, yields the distribution generalization of the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\0& x\leq 0\end{cases}$$ the distribution $2\delta_{x_0}$ will simply integrate to double that.